# A thought about getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

According to this post about [what's news in React 16.3](https://medium.com/@baphemot/whats-new-in-react-16-3-d2c9b7b6193b), in the next update `componentWillReceiveProps` will have a replacement and that is `getDerivedStateFromProps` (the replacement will only happens in 17.0).

The interesting part is that this brand new, static lifecycle method

> is called both on initial mounting and on re-rendering of the
>   component, so you can use it instead of creating state based on props
>   in constructor.

I'm getting confused. So from now on should I need to split my constructor and put the create state logic to this new function instead? I mean the logic when you create state first time your component is created and the logic when you create state from API props is not the same. Putting them together in one method seems not very ideal.

And one more thing is that if I choose to create my state from constructor, this new method will still be called anyway. What a jerk!

What do you think?

Comment: *"What do you think?"* I think you should raise objections to this over on the React issue list, not on SO. The question is either too broad, unclear, opinion-based, or all of the above.

Comment: *"I mean the logic when you create state first time your component is created and the logic when you create state from API props is not the same."* Is it?

Comment: From Dan Abramov : "Please wait for the blog post. It'll explain everything. :-)" He also said that `getDerivedStateFromProps` will be rarely used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let us say we have a list component, that renders a few list items by supplying a few parameters received from it's parent to the API.

1. First we initialise `this.state.data` variable to `[]`.
2. Then using the props, we perform an API call in `componentDidMount()` to assign it to `this.state.data`.
3. Now, these *parameters* coming from the parent are subject to change, so you had to repeat the procedure in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

I think this is the likely scenario that `getDerivedStateFromProps` is targeting. Now instead of updating state from props twice, you only need to write it once in the function: `getDerivedStateFromProps`. As the name suggests, use it **when state has to be derived from the props**.

Points to keep in mind:

You still need to set initial state in constructor. The logic for both initial state and deriving state from props can be very different. For example, if you do not initialise the `data` variable to `[]` and you are mapping over `this.state.data` it would fail as the API has not returned the results to be set in `getDerivedStateFromProps` yet.

Even though `getDerivedStateFromProps` can't use `this`, it works in the same way that `this.setState` does.

That is, if you return

```
{
  data: response.data
}
```

it wouldn't update the other state variables that you have set in constructor. Also you have an option to return `null` to signify no change.

From:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      externalData: []
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    asyncLoadData(this.props.someId).then(externalData =>
     this.setState({ externalData })
    );
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    asyncLoadData(this.props.someId).then(externalData =>
     this.setState({ externalData })
    );
  }
}
```

To:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      externalData: []
    }
  }
  static deriveStateFromProps(props, state, prevProps) {
    if (prevProps === null || props.someValue !== prevProps.someValue) {
      return {
        derivedData: computeDerivedState(props)
      };
    }

    // Return null to indicate no change to state.
    return null;
  }
}
```

Note: I'm just noting an instance from pure React perspective.

Also read [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) from React Blog.

Answer (score 6):

The key difference is that in React 16 **componentWillReceiveProps** is not called on the inital render, only when new props are received. This means you would in your case, create derived state on first load in the constructor, then use **componentWillReceiveProps** on update.

With the new **getDerivedStateFromProps** this logic can be written in this function only, as it runs on both inital mount **and** updates.

> React doesn’t call componentWillReceiveProps() with initial props
>   during mounting. It only calls this method if some of component’s
>   props may update. Calling this.setState() generally doesn’t trigger
>   componentWillReceiveProps().

**In regards to your question regarding API's** to me that would be dependent on how the component is set up, seems to me like it would be logical to make the API call in a parent component, that way you can control how the props are passed down and make the component receiving the props as dumb as possible. State can still be set in a method after making the API call.

As Dan Abramov states, passing props to state is usually a bad idea, this function will be used infrequently is designed to be used when your state depends on how props change over time.

[Props to state as an anti-practice](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/953613666867441664)
and
[a potential use case](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/953612246634188800).

[React - componentWillReceiveProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)